# selenium login failed with yahoo japan

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to log in to Yahoo Japan advertisement platform, after filled in username and password, and click login button, I am supposed to redirect to next page, but instead I got stuck with the login page. If I click the login button manually, it works as promised.

Here's the code snippet I've implemented:

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1200,1013')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://login.bizmanager.yahoo.co.jp/login?url=https://promotionalads.business.yahoo.co.jp/ols/ss/accounts/941550/campaigns/#/')
username = config.SECRET['K']['USER']
password = config.SECRET['K']['PSWD']
username_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#user_name')
username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#password')
password_input.send_keys(password)
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.yjBtnViewLogin')
login_btn.click()
```

I should be redirected to https://promotionalads.business.yahoo.co.jp, please give me some suggestions, thank you guys.

Update:
I compare the login form submitted by clicking login button, there is an hidden input which name is _crumb. This value is showing correctly in Form Data if manually clicking login button, but it will not work if using selenium. I am wondering if this is the reason cause the problem.

Comment: Did you check for any error messages?

Comment: I don't see any error messages showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem, not a tricky way. When I got redirect to login.php, simply enter username and password again, then problem solved.